# Closed Loop with PID controller

Tags: circuit-design, pid-controller

[image: Closed Loop with PID controller]

I have designed this circuit and I expect the output to converge to 1 when stimulating it with a step input. The problem is that I get almost 10 times the input as output. Is there something wrong with the design or am I measuring the output from the wrong place? I am currently measuring the output voltage before R20. The op-amps serve the following purpose from left to right:

```
1st: The summing point of the negative feedback and the input.
2nd: The three parallel op-amps are the P I and D stages of the PID controller
3rd: The summer of the three PID stages.
4th: The inverter of the PID output.
5th and 6th: Realization of the following transfer function:
```

$$
\ G(s) = \frac{100*20*100}{(s+10)(s+20)(s+100)}\,
$$

Comment: The output of U2 should be 0 volts when the system is stable with a constant demand at the input; is it? If it isn't (within millivolts) then there's something wrong.

Comment: Also your transfer function only contains negative complex poles and this cannot, I believe, be created with the third order filter you have implemented. From this I kind of deduce that the whole circuit is oscillating. Is it a sim or a real circuit and do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: Do you mean there is something wrong with the design? I have simulated the output of U2 with Matlab and it is in fact 0. The problem is with the actual circuit. The multimeter doesn't show 0 as you have pointed out but I can't seem to pinpoint the problem. Do you have any ideas as to where I could be making a mistake? G(s) is actually working by itself and with a step input (DC voltage with amplitude 1) does, in fact, produce 10 as output both in the sim and in the actual circuit. Am I making a mistake with the negative feedback connection or with the input connection with the PID connected?

Comment: What is the integrator output. I bet it is end stopped.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: End stopped means output is saturated againsta power rails.

Comment: So does that mean that I have connected the PID wrong? Is the mistake in the design or in the actual circuit?

Comment: If the integrator output is end-stopped then there are instability problems somewhere. On the face of it, the design looks OK but I can't run stability checks in my head. Check the integrator output and if wrong then disconnect the integrator from the summing amplifier. If that doesn't work then disconnect the differential and proportional. Try things, use the power.